# Function that creates pointers to classes

Tags: c++, pointers

I'm trying to create a function that creates pointers to instances of a player class.

This is because, at the start of my game, I want to be able to make as many player instances as I want.

This is to make the game 2-player, 4-player or 3-player and theoretically, an infinite number of players determined by the user's input.

The problem I'm facing is that if I make my function to make pointers like this:

**edit:** player is a user defined class that I made.

```cpp
void createPointer()
{
    player * player1 = new player("George");
}
```

1. The pointer will only be locally declared, resulting in a memory leak, because I can't reference the pointer player1, as it's deleted once the function createPointer() concludes.
2. I wouldn't be able to reference the players correctly, as shown above, as they're all named player1. Makes me think I should use templates in c++ to change the name of the variable each time a player is created.
3. As shown below, I couldn't delete the player instance at the end of the game:

```cpp
void endGame()
{
    //delete the object the pointer
    //is pointing to in memory
    delete player1;
    //set the pointer to point to NULL
    //as default, so can check if pointer is pointing
    //to anything
    player1 = NULL;
}
```

So I was just wondering if there was another approach I could take? I know of one solution which is to globally declare the pointers beforehand. i.e

```cpp
player * player1 = NULL;
player * player2 = NULL;
player * player3 = NULL;
void createPointer()
{
    player1 = new player("George");
}
```

However, this would mean I cannot create a variable number of players without declaring all of them beforehand, as shown in the above example.

Apologies if I am misunderstanding anything, I would highly appreciate any advice whatsoever.

Comment: What you want is a `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<player>> players`. You could also use `std::shared_ptr` if that suites your use case better.

Comment: More broadly speaking, you will want to look into smart pointers, RAII and memory management in modern C++ in general. You seem to have a good understanding of the basics thus far, and this will be an important next step.

Comment: why do you want to use pointers? you want to create players (and get a pointer to them) not just create pointers to players, small difference but confusing the two is a common source of bugs

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 hmm wait uhh I might have gotten it wrong, however, I think it should be okay, I think this line  `player * player1 = new player("George");` make a player pointer as well as a player instance and then makes the player pointer point towards the memory location of the player instance in the stack. I think that should be the case. Otherwise, I shouldn't be able to call the player functions. i.e I did this: `player1.getName()` and it returned a value, I think it might just be c++ with weird syntax though.

Comment: @super thank you for your help, I hadn't heard of unique_ptr before, but I'll be sure to look into it. Just a question, it seems that unique_ptrs clean up the inside of a memory address (i.e the variable/object inside)? However, thank you very much! I think a std::vector<std::unique_ptr<player>> players would be perfect for my case, or even shared_ptr.

Comment: @MaxLanghof Thank you, I'm humbled, but I've barely touched c++ at all, thank you for telling me which direction I should go in next as well, I wasn't sure where to go next to keep learning c++!

Comment: yes, `player * player1 = new player("George");` is creating a player instance and `player1` is a pointer to that instance. I was refering to your title and that maybe `player player1("George");` could also be fine. You do not necessarily have to use dynamic allocations to create objects

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you *really* want to use raw pointers for your players, you can modify your `createPointer` function to return what it has created:

```cpp
player* createPointer()
{
    player* createdPlayer = new player("George");
    // Do whatever you need for initialization!
    return createdPlayer;
}
```

Then, in the code that wants to use such players, do something like:

```cpp
//...
player* player1 = createPointer();
player* player2 = createPointer();
//...
```

Then, when you've done with the players, you can just `delete` each one...

```cpp
delete player1;
delete player2;
```

*A better solution (IMHO) would be to put whatever code you (eventually) have in `createPointer` into the **constructor** definition for the `player` class; then you can just use code like `player *p1 = new player("Harold");` rather than calling a function each time you make a new player.*

But, as mentioned in the comments, you would be better off using either `std::vector` or `std::shared_ptr` objects.

Comment: Thank you for that, I didn't think about using a return statement at all, I'm thinking I'll probably have to use a vector and something like push_back, because the situation I was imagining was the program would ask you for how many players you wanted, so you could type something like 100 and then it would create 100 pointers to 100 player objects. Not sure if that would be a good idea.

Answer (score 5):

You probably need a container of `player` instances. The default container is [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

Something like

```
std::vector<player> players;

players.emplace_back("George"); // Create the first player
players.emplace_back("Fred"); // Create the next player
// etc.
```

You can refer to players by their (0 based) position in `players`

```
players[0].do_stuff(); // George does stuff
```

You can loop over all the players

```
for (auto & player : players) {
    player.take_turn(); // each player in turn does something
}
```

When `players` is destroyed, it automatically cleans up the `player` objects

Comment: Thank you very much, a vector was what I was missing! Although I think I might use a vector of pointers to player objects. Just because if I need to pass the vector to a function it wouldn't take as much memory, just in case a player object is very large or I have a vector of 100 players.

Comment: In that case pass a reference to the vector.

Answer (score 2):

If i understand you correctly,maybe there are two solutions to solve your problem.
Here the codes.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


class Player
{
public:
    Player(string name) :m_name(name) {
        cout << "player " << m_name << " is created\n";
    }
    ~Player()
    {
        cout << "pluaer " << m_name << " is destoryed\n";
    }
private:
    string m_name;
};

//The first solution : return a pointer
Player* creatPlayer_1(const string& name)
{
    return new Player(name);
}

//The second solution : pass a reference of the pointer as the argument
void createPlayer_2(Player*& pPlayer, const string& name)
{
    pPlayer = new Player(name);
}

int main()
{
    Player* pPlayer_one = creatPlayer_1("one");

    Player* pPlayer_two = nullptr;
    createPlayer_2(pPlayer_two, "two");

    delete pPlayer_one;
    delete pPlayer_two;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I think I'll be using something like this, perhaps with a vector for a variable number of players, thank you for going to the effort of coding this up.